# Mutli-threading - how to safely remove from ArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

My program has a lot of `threads` which can at any time do `for each throught an arraylist` but also any `item` in the `arraylist` can be removed at any time, how do I prevent removing the `item` from `arraylist` when the `arraylist` is in use by some other `thread`?

I would really appreciate some explanation or code example.

Comment: Use read/write locks.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this. Synchroninization blocks, uses correct data structure (CopyOnWriteArrayList), read write locks, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use an `ArrayList`, instead use a suitable class such as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. However if there are a lot of modifications (and big lists), it will affect performance.

Comment: From the javadoc for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (emphasis is mine): "This is _ordinarily too costly_, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations _vastly_ outnumber mutations, and is useful when you cannot or _don't want to synchronize traversals._"  The last bit may be the most important.  If thread A modifies the list while thread B is traversing it, then thread B will be traversing an _out-of-date_ version of the list.  Will that work?  Only the designer of the application knows for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Use Collections.synchronizedList() to get a thread-safe version of your list:

```
List<T> list = Collections.synchronizedList(yourArray);
```

Then use an iterator while going throught the list and call the remove() method on the iterator to remove an item:

```
Iterator<T> it = list.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(condition) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use A thread-safe variant of `ArrayList` -  [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1):

If multiple threads access an `ArrayList` instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the `Collections.synchronizedList` method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the list:

```
   List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: This is an exact copy of [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).